# jQuery stop event propagation - more than once

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write a form that sends a JSON request to the server when a button on the form is clicked. I want to disable the default form behaviour so that clicking the button is what will do the job of sending an email address. The idea is to return a message from the server back to the form (if an error), or to replace the form with a success message (on success).

This is what I have so far (snippet):

```
<div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div id="invite-member">
            <p>Enter your email:</p>
            <div class="no-show error-msg"></div>
            <form id="frm-invite" method="post" autocomplete="off" action='www.example.com/backend.php' accept-charset="UTF-8">
                <div class="input-append">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" class="input-long">
                    <button id="btn-invite" class="btn btn-primary btn-success" type="submit">Add me »</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn-invite").click(function(e){
        alert('Woohoo');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
</script>
```

The first time the page is loaded, the button behaves as expected. The subsequent times though (without reloading the page), the event binding seems to have been 'broken' and the browser wants to go to www.example.com/backend.php.

Why is that?.

Comment: Use `e.preventDefault()` instead of `e.stopPropagation()`, or handle `form.submit()` with an event handler instead.

Comment: Also, use `$("form").submit(function` rather than `$("button").click(function` otherwise the form can still be submitted by pressing enter.

Comment: @Archer you comment is a good answer and should be presented as one.

Comment: @KevinB agree, but they did state they would replace the form with success message

Comment: If my understanding is correct from the above comments, then I should handle the for.submit event and add a `preventDefault()` - thus effectively disabling the form default behaviour (i.e. Enter will no longer submit the form), and then also handle the button click like I am currently doing, but with a `preventDefault()` instead of `stopPropagation()`? - right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to write a form that sends a JSON request to the server
>   when a button on the form is clicked

In that case binding to the form submit may be better to prevent other means of submitting the form which cricumvent the button click.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on("submit", function(e){
        $.ajax({
         // do you thing...
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

[**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is only usable in jQuery 1.7 and later, replace it with [**bind()**](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) if you are using a version of jQuery lower than 1.7

Also note that `return false;` is equal to both, `event.preventDefault();` and `event.stopPropagation();`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `preventDefault` instead of `stopPropagation`.

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/Vr3Ey/1/).

Comment: You do realise that there's a **Javascript** pane in JSFiddle and there's no need to put it in the **HTML** pane?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Yes, but this is a simple example and I simply used the code provided. I'm quite aware of the huge "Javascript" pane.

Answer (score 0):

Use e.preventDefault() to stop the buttons normal behaviour

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn-invite").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();        

    //do ajax


    });
});
```

Comment: ...and call `preventDefault()` first thing in handler and not as last one as OP did.